# how to assign key to each string in the list of strings using python

Tags: python

I have the below list for example consider:

```
my_list = ['1,ad,help,green','2,bc,quote,green','3,ef,mask,red','4,ad,help,green']
```

I need the output list to be like:

```
output = ['Rule:1,Key:ad,Message:help,Status:green','Rule:2,Key:bc,Message:quote,Status:green','Rule:3,Key:ef,Message:mask,Status:red','Rule:4,Key:ad,Message:help,Status:green']
```

also how to traverse through the above list and identify the rule, key, message and status and print them alone like below

```
Rule:1
Key:ad
Message:help
Status:green
```

Need help on this.

I have tried the below:

```
for i in my_list:
    for j in i:
        output.append(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need the output list to be like:

##### solution

The idea is just to split each string and then format the output string accordingly.

```py
output = ["Rule:{},Key:{},Message:{},Status:{}".format(*s.split(',')) for s in my_list]
```

##### demo

```py
my_list = ['1,ad,help,green','2,bc,quote,green','3,ef,mask,red','4,ad,help,green']
output = ["Rule:{},Key:{},Message:{},Status:{}".format(*s.split(',')) for s in my_list]
print(output)
```

- output

  ```
  ['Rule:1,Key:ad,Message:help,Status:green', 'Rule:2,Key:bc,Message:quote,Status:green', 'Rule:3,Key:ef,Message:mask,Status:red', 'Rule:4,Key:ad,Message:help,Status:green']
  ```

---

> How to traverse through the above list

##### for another question

There are different way, here is a simple one

```py
for line in output:
    for entry in line.split(","):
        [key,value] = entry.split(":")    # this is the traverse through
```

Comment: Thankyou @Xin Cheng.. can you also let me know how to iterate through this list of strings and get the output as below

Rule:1 
Key:ad 
Message:help 
Status:green

Comment: Updated the solution with your updates 

Answer (score 0):

With a list comprehension:

```
my_list = ['1,ad,help,green','2,bc,quote,green','3,ef,mask,red','4,ad,help,green']
words = ['Rule', 'Key', 'Message', 'Status']

out = [','.join([':'.join(x) for x in zip(words, s.split(','))]) for s in my_list]
```

Output:

```
['Rule:1,Key:ad,Message:help,Status:green',
 'Rule:2,Key:bc,Message:quote,Status:green',
 'Rule:3,Key:ef,Message:mask,Status:red',
 'Rule:4,Key:ad,Message:help,Status:green']
```

##### print as several lines

```
for s in my_list:
    for x in zip(words, s.split(',')):
        print(*x, sep=':')
```

Output:

```
Rule:1
Key:ad
Message:help
Status:green
Rule:2
Key:bc
Message:quote
Status:green
Rule:3
Key:ef
Message:mask
Status:red
Rule:4
Key:ad
Message:help
Status:green
```

Comment: Thankyou @mozway.. can you also let me know how to iterate through this list of strings and get the output as below

Rule:1 
Key:ad 
Message:help 
Status:green

Comment: Check if the update is what you want